# Is Windows Vista worth considering when developing for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp

Quite a few comments to answers in a different post, *[Where are the best locations to write an error log in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191609/where-are-the-best-locations-to-write-an-error-log-in-windows)*, gave me the impression that a lot of things regarding standard folders (`%APPDATA%`; `%TEMP%`) in Windows Vista are different from Windows XP, which should of course be taken into account when developing software that will have to run under Windows  at some point.

But in my company, I do not see that happen in this decade, and maybe not in the next either. I mean, the central IT deployed SP2 only eight months ago, and any question about SP3 is met with disregard (well, if you're lucky...)

So what is your advice? Should I rewrite two modules in my current project to make them ready for Windows Vista, or should I not bother about it at all, until it is really needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I'd have a quick look at the effort level of what it would take to enable "Vista Support" in your application.

If the effort levels are acceptable based on the allotted time to make changes in your project then it's good to account for the future in any design.

You know your implementation better than anyone!

We've had some issues in-house here with shortcuts and such as they were generated in an older installation suite. It's the little things that we are currently addressing in getting our Vista Support fully up and running. I'm sure there will be some "unforeseen" obstacles you will come across as well.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 11):

Make them Vista-ready, if only for the fact that Windows 7 will have the same changes. Better to future-proof now when you have the chance, than later when time is critical.

Answer (score 6):

The big thing for supporting Windows Vista in most desktop applications is to use references like your %APPDATA% rather than hard-coding paths. That should resolve any changed folder locations. And don't do anything that requires write access in your program's install folder.

Interestingly, these rules are true for Windows XP, too. It's just that in the past it was a lot easier to get away with breaking them.

Comment: +1! I don't know why this isn't getting more upvotes. There are a number of low-impact changes -- like this -- which make your app more-or-less future proof against any Windows upgrades. Check http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/ to read the horror stories when developers break these rules ...

Comment: indeed, breaking, like having users as admin by default(and with no UAC, its bad indeed), crap like that. So you get apps that require admin priviledges.

Comment: It's a function of how many views the question receives, and an answer posted on a Friday won't get many views.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to hurry. So far it is not critical, and who knows what next the version of Windows would look like.

Comment: An MSDN subscription can get you a lot of details on upcoming versions of Microsoft software. Vista's changes weren't all of a sudden launched on all of us, just those of us without the MSDN subscription. Windows 7 isn't looking much different, and they're already starting tech previews.

Comment: And you can see what windows will looks like if you search on google. Windows 7 will be an upgrade of windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

If you planning on upgrading your software for Windows Vista, check out *[Windows Logo Program, Requirements for the Windows Vista Logo Program for Software](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/e/4/8e4c929d-679a-4238-8c21-2dcc8ed1f35c/Windows%20Vista%20Software%20Logo%20Spec%201.1.doc)* (Microsoft Word document, 183 KB, file name *Windows Vista Software Logo Spec 1.1.doc*).

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't foresee an OS upgrade in the near future, don't worry too much about it. You should, however, keep the potential for an OS upgrade in mind whenever you're changing code. If anything is OS-specific in a section of code when you make changes, tweak it so that it is either OS-independent or easy to locate and modify later to make it OS-independent (depending on how long it would take to update it).

If you get into a situation where you're just tackling lesser issues, consider specifically aiming your fixes towards areas that you know (or suspect might) have code that would need to be adjusted if your company upgraded to Vista or Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother, Windows 7 is coming out relatively soon, you'd be best off waiting to see what changes they make to support that! Last thing you want is to spend time fixing things for Vista..... and then fixing them all over again for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Is your company going to upgrade to Windows Vista at all? A lot of companies are ignoring Windows Vista and are planning to upgrade to the next Windows version when it comes out in the hopes that it will suck less than Windows Vista. If this is the case, it would be a complete waste of time.  Who knows what will change in the next version of Windows. It is better to rewrite once for the new Windows than to rewrite once for Windows Vista and then again for the next Windows version.

Comment: Chances are the standard folders system won't be changing between Vista and Windows 7, likewise the other systems already changed between XP and Vista will only be updated, not replaced. Things that are similar between XP and Vista, on the other hand...

Comment: Would you be willing to bet your job on that?  I wouldn't.